# Uniform Convergence of Series tends to $f(x)$

Tags: real-analysis

The question is to prove that:

$$\frac{f_1(x)+\cdots+f_n(x)}{n}$$ tends to $f(x)$ uniformly on $E$, as $n$ tends to infinity.

I am not sure how to do this generically without an actual sequence. (i.e $f_n(x) = x^n$)

Comment: My thought is to set up the | ∑ n(x) - (x)| < ℇ based on the definition of uniformity, but not sure where to go from there.

Comment: As written, the question makes no sense. You could for instance take $f_n(x)=0$ for all $n$ and all $x$, and take $f(x)=x$, say.

Comment: That's what the book says.

Comment: Well, if you assume that $f_n(x)$ tends to $f(x)$, then there will be some $N$ such that $|f_N(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon$, for all $\epsilon$. Then, you basically have $ \frac{\Sigma_n f(x)}{n} = f(x)$, if I'm correct...

Comment: Yes we can assume n(x) tends to (x).  That is probably it.  How do you get the ∑ (x)/n?

Comment: Intuitively, $\frac{f_1(x) + f_2(x) + ... + f_n(x)}{n}  = \frac{f_1(x) + f_2(x) + ... + f_{N-1}(x)}{n} + \frac{f_N(x) + f_{N+1}(x) + ...}{n}$. As $n$ becomes large, and since $N$ is finite (for some $\epsilon$) the first part will tend to zero. The rest will just be a sum of functions that are very close to $f(x)$ ($n- N$ of them) which you will divide by $n$. Note that $n - N$ is almost $n$ when $n$ gets very large. That's not very rigorous, but the idea is there

Comment: I think that is probably just what they are looking for.  I wasn't sure how to put it in that form.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume that $f_n(x)$ tends to $f(x)$, then, intuitively we'll have

$\frac{f_1(x) + f_2(x) + ... +f_n(x)}{n} = \frac{f_1(x) + ... + f_{N-1}(x)}{n} + \frac{f_N(x) + ... + f_n(x)}{n}$, where you can get $|f_N(x) -f(x)| < \epsilon$ for sufficiently large $N$. Then, as $n$ becomes large, and since $N$ is finite (for some $\epsilon$) the first part will tend to zero. The rest will just be a sum of functions that are very close to $f(x)$ ($n - N$ of them) which you will divide by $n$. Note that $n-N$ is almost $n$ when $n$ gets very large. Not very rigorous, but the idea is there